# Instalando Parse no Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio, parse

Olá, estou tendo dificuldades em instalar o Parse no meu projeto, eu incluo a biblioteca(Parse-1.11.0.jar) na pasta libs, altero o manifest.xml com as permissões, na classe java, no método OnCreate eu incluo a chamada, no Gradle eu incluo na dependencies as informações de compile, mas sempre da esse erro:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Alguma dica?Agradeço a ajuda antecipadamente.

Comment: Esta é uma mensagem genérica de erro. Olha no `Gradle Console` e procure pelo erro real, geralmente vem antes dessa mensagem.

Comment: Se eu entendi bem o que você botou, além de adicionar o `.jar`, você também está adicionando a dependência no arquivo gradle. Você precisa importar a biblioteca de um ou outro jeito, não dos dois. Como dito na própria página do Parser no Github: `Download the latest JAR or define in Gradle`. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android

Comment: agradeço a atenção , acabei conseguindo resolver.
Eu apenas não declarei as informações de compilação no gradle, contrariando o que diz a própria página do parse e compilou certinho.

Comment: Obrigado Luiz, deu certo! Resolvi apenas incluindo na libs.